# is there simple method to get hijri date as DateTime?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, datetime, hijri

I found answer to [hijri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hijri_year) date in [Islamic calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_calendar) but the code is very complex.

## The Question

---

is there simple function to get it as `DateTime` type ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/index.html) API [IslamicChronology](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/chrono/IslamicChronology.html). It's not part of the Android API, download the JAR and add it to your build path to use it in Android projects.

See Joda-Time documentation for [Islamic calendar system](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/cal_islamic.html).

Example code taken from that documentation:

```
// setup date object for midday on May Day 2004 (ISO year 2004)
DateTime dtISO = new DateTime(2004, 5, 1, 12, 0, 0, 0);

// find out what the same instant is using the Islamic Chronology
DateTime dtIslamic = dtISO.withChronology(IslamicChronology.getInstance());
```

Comment: I've not used the Islamic calendar features, but otherwise I can recommend Joda-Time highly. Hopefully Kovács Imre does not mind, I added some example code from the doc. Also, Joda-Time inspired the new [java.time.* classes](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) coming in Java 8, defined by JSR 310. I'm not sure if the new JSR 310 features include support for calendaring systems such as Hijri – I don't see any mention in a quick perusal.

Comment: JSR-310 does not contain the same islamic calendar as JodaTime. In the first case it is the Umalqra-calendar of Saudi-Arabia. The KACST (national science agency in Saudi-Arabia) has sent tabular data to Oracle to enable the sighting-based JSR-310 implementation, while JodaTime solution uses a calculatory approach. So different results are expected.